# Dynamic Start menu WinRT tile for a normal desktop WPF application on Windows 10?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, windows-runtime, windows-10

I remember that live tiles on Win8/8.1.x were possible with store apps.

With the release of Windows 10, has this changed? Did any new solutions appear in the time since this question was last asked (besides the devexpress control)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll soon be able to use **project centennial** to do things like this: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-692

Comment: I kinda wanted to have it he other way around. Have some WinRT features brought to the desktop, not my desktop app brought to the store. I'd still like it to zip my app and send it around and don't mind the Store.

Comment: Currently no way to do that, sorry. Maybe you could manually get a tile in there and use a service to update it regularly, like this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865 but updated, not static.